# React typescript MUI Autocomplete, setting default value not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I have `React` `Typescript` code using MUI with use hook form. for Autocomplete filed setting default value is not working, giving below error message.

looking some help to set the default value.

> Type '{ id: number; name: string; }[]' is missing the following
> properties from type 'Product': id, namets(2739)
> useAutocomplete.d.ts(103, 3): The expected type comes from property
> 'defaultValue' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> AutocompleteProps<Product, false, false, false, "div

**Code Sanbox link**

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-bhabha-uhti49?file=/src/CarAutoComplete.tsx

**Code:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { Select, MenuItem, Autocomplete } from "@mui/material";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

export interface Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface FormFields {
 
  selectedProducts: Array<Product>;
}

export default function Demo() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Array<Product>>([
    { id: 1, name: "Mouse" },
    { id: 2, name: "Printer" },
    { id: 3, name: "Monitor" },
    { id: 4, name: "server" }
  ]);

  const initFormFieldValues = {    
    selectedProducts: [{ id: 1, name: "Mouse" }]
  };

  const methods = useForm<FormFields>({
    defaultValues: initFormFieldValues
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: FormFields) => alert(JSON.stringify(data));

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "400px", margin: "20px" }}>
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        
        <Controller
          control={methods.control}
          name={"selectedProducts"}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <Autocomplete
              
              id="product-selection"
              options={products}
              getOptionLabel={(product) => product.name}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  variant="standard"
                  label="Select a Product"
                  placeholder="Type to filter list"
                />
              )}
              onChange={(_, data) => {
                onChange(data);
                return data;
              }}
              defaultValue={initFormFieldValues.selectedProducts}
            />
          )}
        />

        <Button variant="contained" style={{ margin: "5px" }} type="submit">
          Send
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have mixed usage of selection of single and multiple values of [mui autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#multiple-values).

If you want the user to select only a single value, you need to change:

```
export interface FormFields {
 
  selectedProducts: Array<Product>;
}
```

to:

```
export interface FormFields {
  selectedProducts: Product;
}
```

and change:

```
  const initFormFieldValues = {    
    selectedProducts: [{ id: 1, name: "Mouse" }]
  };
```

to

```
  const initFormFieldValues = {
    selectedProducts: { id: 1, name: "Mouse" }
  };
```

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-autocomplete-single?file=src%2FCarAutocomplete.jsx) for a live working example of single selection.

If you want the user to select multiple values, you need to change:

```
  const initFormFieldValues = {    
    selectedProducts: [{ id: 1, name: "Mouse" }]
  };
```

to:

```
  const initFormFieldValues = {
    selectedProducts: [products[0]]
  };
```

and add `multiple` prop to autocomplete like this:

```
<Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="product-selection"
```

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-autocomplete-multiple?file=src%2FCarAutocomplete.jsx) for a live working example of multiple selection.